# Pattern matching inside for loop in Ocaml

Tags: for-loop, pattern-matching, ocaml, computer-science

I want to use pattern matching while using for loop 
Is it possible for me to use it

This question is related to Ocaml

Comment: It really depends on how you use pattern matching in the for loop. Could you post some code or at least some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

A `match` expression in OCaml is just an expression. It can appear anywhere you can have an expression. The body of a `for` loop is an expression, so yes you can have a `match` expression there.

(If you have such basic questions about OCaml you would probably learn much more quickly by working through a tutorial than by asking questions here on StackOverflow.)